# SQL Server 2005 need to create fake columns in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Hi All this is going to be a very strange question and all my searching has resulted in no good answers. The basic problem will help me solve two problems one in Crystal Reports and one in SSRS 2005. I have reports in both that need the same kind of solution. please bear with me as the explanation will be a bit lengthy.

I need to use SSRS in an unusual fashion. The reports I need to create will only have minimal data and will be printed and filled in by hand in the field. They are being used as form printing program in this case.

The reports will have a tablix/Matrix control on them and I need to create it with a specific # of columns regardless of if the data exists for those columns or not. In one case (SSRS), there are no fields that are being used as data fields that will be summed.

I have data for the rows and columns, but what I need is to create the matrix/tablix with 10 columns. So if the recordset  has only 2 instances of the data that will make the columns, I still want to see all 10 columns but the headers being blank.

So it would look something like this:

```
                         Col1|Col2|Col3|Fake1|Fake2|Fake3|......
Row1
Row2
Row3
.....
```

So if I have 1 column or 10 columns worth of data I still want to display 10 columns 2 with real headers and 8 with blank headers.

Here is the SQL I'm using. this is the basis for a matrix in SSRS 2005. The Employee ID and Name are the rows. the JobAccount_Tracking_ID is the column.
A record can have from 1 to 10 tracking_ids.

What I want to return is a total of 10 tracking IDs regardless of the actual number of tracking IDs. The extras would show up in the matrix as blank columns.

```
Declare @FieldLogID as int
Set @FieldLogID = 1018

SELECT DISTINCT
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Employee_EmployeeID, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Employee_FullName, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Injured_Today_Custom, 
CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1.JobAccount_TrackingID, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.StartDateTime, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.StopDateTime, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.WorkHours
FROM
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee AS CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount AS CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1 
ON CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID = CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID
WHERE CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID = @FieldLogID
```

Any ideas how I can do this? In the SSRS case I can't create a view in the database as it is a vendor's db.

Comment: Couldn't you just select `null` or `''` (blank) or something?

Comment: Your report table has a minimum of 10 rows and 10 columns, right? What if your `select` brings more than 10 rows? Do you still have to show only 10 rows or show as many rows it generates? Can you edit the SS query or you have to solve this inside SSRS and Crystal Reports?

Comment: I'm not concerned about the amount of Rows, just the amount of Columns. For SSRS I need to solve this within SSRS. For the crystal report (similar situation but not the same report) I can create a view or SP to solve the issue.

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I kinda get what you're going for, but in any case I'd recommend you either let us know what SQL code you have so far and be more specific about the problem, or split the question in two (SSRS vs Crystal) and tell us what you tried in both report setups, respectively. As it stands the question is a bit too broad imo.

Comment: @Jeron, I've edited it and hopefully clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the logic:

1. Union the main query to a subquery containing 10 additional unions (assuming the max is 10). The 10 unions will use a fake TrakingID. zzz01 through zzz10 in this case to ensure they show last in the sort. If the TrackingID is an Integer, use 9999990 to 9999999.
2. Enclose the whole thing in an outer query that uses a ranking function such as Row_Number() to rank the rows by partitioning them on userID and sorting on TrackingID. The zzz or 999999 will ensure the fake ones come last.
3. Enclose the whole thing again in one more outer query that uses the ranking function in a where clause to grab the first 10. This will get you the existing tracking ids plus the remaining fake ones up to 10.

here is the code:

```
Declare @FieldLogID as int
Set @FieldLogID = 1018

Select Employee_EmployeeID,
Employee_FullName,
Injured_Today_Custom,
Case when JobAccount_TrackingID like'zzz%' then Null else JobAccount_TrackingID end as JobAccount_TrackingID,
StartDateTime, 
StopDateTime, 
WorkHours
from 
(
Select row_number() over (partition by Employee_EmployeeID order by JobAccount_TrackingID) row,*
from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Employee_EmployeeID, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Employee_FullName, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.Injured_Today_Custom, 
CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1.JobAccount_TrackingID, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.StartDateTime, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.StopDateTime, 
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.WorkHours
FROM
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee AS CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount AS CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1 
ON CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID = CustomizedFieldLogJobAccount_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID
WHERE CustomizedFieldLogEmployee_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID = @FieldLogID
Union
Select Distinct 
Employee_EmployeeID,
Employee_FullName,
null as Injured_Today_Custom,
fake_TrackingID,
null as StartDateTime, 
null as StopDateTime, 
null as WorkHours
FROM
CustomizedFieldLogEmployee
cross join
(
Select 'zzz01' fake_TrackingID
union Select 'zzz02' 
union Select 'zzz03' 
union Select 'zzz04' 
union Select 'zzz05' 
union Select 'zzz06' 
union Select 'zzz07' 
union Select 'zzz08' 
union Select 'zzz09' 
union Select 'zzz10' 
) a where FieldLog_FieldLogID = @FieldLogID
) b 
) c where Row<=10 
order by Employee_EmployeeID,JobAccount_TrackingID
```

Comment: If you get an error then please let me know the format of your trackinID field and I will send you revised code.

Comment: Did this work for you? If not please let me know, otherwise please mark the question as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam I'm trying that now. I had a 4 day weekend and this is th e1st I've had to get back to you.

Comment: Sam, Thanks that pretty much works, but the format of the Trackingfield ID is "0401-01004" or occasionally "0401-01004.a". so 4 digits-5digits. None of the tracking IDs begin with a 9999 from what I'm given to understand.

Comment: I had to make a couple of changes, but it works. Thank you very much. Can I use something like this to force a specific number of rows? I.E. only have n number of employees show and the rest be blank if less than n?

Comment: Do you mean making the total number of rows dynamic instead of hard coded? This query won't do that because the number of rows is determined by the number of unions, but lookup "sql recursive queries" in Google and you'll find some ideas. I'll try digging into it further when I have time later this week.

Comment: Right now the rows are dynamic based on the data in the table. However if the table has less and only less than 9 rows in it can I force it to be 9 or however many rows we decide? The business just wants the grids to fill the page.

Comment: Yes, if you want a total of 9 rows, include 9 select statements joined by union and then change the where clause to be where Row<=9

Comment: Thanks for that. Here is a followup since the users have decided to change their requirements.
The users would now like to see two side by side tables of 6 rows each. So essentially 2 6x6 tables. How they want it to work is weird. If there are more than 6 rows, they want the rest of the records to flow over to the 2nd table. I keep trying to tell them that this is not a form printing program but a program designed to report what is in the database. 

I've done some searching, but can't figure out how to split a single recordset into two tables.